# Query based on condition in dynamo db table

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to know if I can do a query like SQL "in" statement in DynamoDB.
for example, if I have a table called class and it has 6 grades student's name. 
I want to find student's name from first to third grade. 
In sql I can do something like this "select student_name from class where grade in (1,2,3)"
My question is how can I do it this in DynamoDB ? Thanks

Comment: I am using Python

Comment: are you using boton3??? and pls share us a example file of your table in format csv if you can